# Counting values in table joined several times

Tags: sql, join, count

I have a problem counting a table joined several times.

The `question` table :

```
+----+----------+
| id | question |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Foo?     |
+----+----------+
```

The `answer` one :

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | question_id | choice |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |      1 |
|  2 |           1 |      1 |
|  3 |           1 |      1 |
|  4 |           1 |      2 |
|  5 |           1 |      3 |
|  6 |           1 |      3 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

The expected result :

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| question | num_1 | num_2 | num_3 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| Foo?     |     3 |     1 |     2 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The (failing) query and its result :

```
SELECT
    q.question AS question,
    COUNT(a1.id) AS num_1,
    COUNT(a2.id) AS num_2,
    COUNT(a3.id) AS num_3
FROM
    question q
    LEFT JOIN answer a1 ON a1.question_id = q.id AND a1.choice = 1
    LEFT JOIN answer a2 ON a2.question_id = q.id AND a2.choice = 2
    LEFT JOIN answer a3 ON a3.question_id = q.id AND a3.choice = 3
GROUP BY
        q.id

+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| question | num_1 | num_2 | num_3 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| Foo?     |     6 |     6 |     6 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I don't understand why I get this result.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `choice = 1` gives 3 rows, `choice = 2` gives 1 row, `choice = 3` gives 2 rows and `1 * 2 * 3 = 6`. if you remove the `group by` and aggregates and look at the results it should be clear. You can use

```
SELECT
    q.question AS question,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.choice = 1 THEN 1 END) AS num_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.choice = 2 THEN 1 END) AS num_2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.choice = 3 THEN 1 END) AS num_3
FROM
    question q
    LEFT JOIN answer a ON a.question_id = q.id AND a.choice IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY
        q.id,
        q.question
```

Comment: +1. Wouldn't you need to add ", q.question" to the end of your GROUP BY clause? Your SELECT has q.question which would give an "q.question is INVALID in SELECT list" error.

Comment: @Arun - I assume the OP is on MySQL where [this isn't a requirement](http://mysql.lamphost.net/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html) from the fact the query in the question works but I agree it should be added in (even though it is clearly functionally dependant on `q.id` and won't affect the results)

Comment: thank you very much for throwing more light into this! The link is definitely helpful.

Comment: Note that `a.choice BETWEEN 1 AND 3` is ever so slightly faster, and that adding the extra `group by` clause slows things down _very slightly_ on MySQL for no benefit. And maybe _(you'll know this better than I)_ `sum(a.choice = 2) as num_2` will be slightly faster than the `count(case....`

Comment: @Johan using `sum(a.choice = 2)` doesn't work, it returns the same results as the one returned in my initial query.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your query without the counts and grouping, you'll see you get results like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| q    | num1 | num2 | num3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| foo  |    1 |    4 |    5 |
| foo  |    1 |    4 |    6 |
| foo  |    2 |    4 |    5 |
| foo  |    2 |    4 |    6 |
| foo  |    3 |    4 |    5 |
| foo  |    3 |    4 |    6 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

As expected, 6 rows, so each aliased field will give you a count of 6. Martin Smith's got the right answer above.